# Non-deprecated means of setting object mapping

Tags: objective-c, ios, restkit

I have a Ruby On Rails local server running which serves me the following JSON:

```
[ { "content" : "Here is content",
    "created_at" : "2012-10-07T01:06:51Z",
    "id" : 4,
    "name" : "Joe",
    "title" : "Title 1",
    "updated_at" : "2012-10-07T01:06:51Z"
  },
  { "content" : "Here is content",
    "created_at" : "2012-10-07T01:07:09Z",
    "id" : 5,
    "name" : "John",
    "title" : "Title2",
    "updated_at" : "2012-10-07T01:07:09Z"
  }
]
```

I am using RestKit to parse this into `Post` model objects like so:

```
- (void)loadObjects
{
    RKObjectMapping *objectMapping = [RKObjectMapping mappingForClass:[Post class]];
    [objectMapping mapKeyPath:@"id" toAttribute:@"postId"];
    [objectMapping mapKeyPath:@"created_at" toAttribute:@"createdAt"];
    [objectMapping mapKeyPath:@"content" toAttribute:@"content"];
    [objectMapping mapKeyPath:@"title" toAttribute:@"title"];
    [objectMapping mapKeyPath:@"name" toAttribute:@"name"];
    [objectMapping mapKeyPath:@"updated_at" toAttribute:@"updatedAt"];

    RKObjectManager* manager = [RKObjectManager objectManagerWithBaseURLString:@"http://localhost:3000/"];
    [manager loadObjectsAtResourcePath:@"/posts" objectMapping:objectMapping delegate:self];
}

- (void)objectLoader:(RKObjectLoader *)objectLoader didLoadObjects:(NSArray *)objects {
    NSLog(@"%@", objects);
}
```

This works fine, however the `loadObjectsAtResourcePath:objectMapping:delegate:` is deprecated. I assume I should therefore be using `loadObjectsAtResourcePath:delegate:`, but I cannot figure out a way to set the `objectMapping`. Any thoughts?

**Update**

I am now setting the delegate like so:

```
[manager loadObjectsAtResourcePath:@"/posts" usingBlock:^(RKObjectLoader *loader) {
    loader.objectMapping = objectMapping;
    loader.delegate = self;
}];
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [restkit documentation](http://restkit.org/api/master/Classes/RKObjectManager.html#//api/name/loadObjectsAtResourcePath%3ausingBlock%3a) says that if you use `loadObjectsAtResourcePath:usingBlock:` you can set the objectMapping from inside the a block.

```
- (void)loadObjectUsingBlockExample {
    [[RKObjectManager sharedManager] loadObjectsAtResourcePath:@"/monkeys.json" usingBlock:^(RKObjectLoader *loader) {
        loader.objectMapping = [[RKObjectManager sharedManager].mappingProvider objectMappingForClass:[Monkey class]];
    }];
}
```

Comment: OK that makes sense, but how doe I set the `RKObjectLoaderDelegate` delegate on the `RKObjectManager` to get the call back for `objectLoader:didLoadObjects:`. Can I also do that in the block?